# Generate Pandas DataFrames from CSV file list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

To frame the question. I am searching a directory for all csv files. I am saving the path of each csv file along with the delineation into a DataFrame. I know want to iterate over the DataFrame, and read in the specific csv file into a dataframe with a name generated from the original filename. I cannot figure out how to dynamically generate these dataframes. I started coding a few days ago so apologies if the syntax is poor.

```
# Looks in a given directory and all subsequent subdirectories for the extension ".csv"
# Reads path to all csv files and creates a list

PATH = "Z:\Adam"
EXT = "*.csv"
all_csv_files = [file
                 for path, subdir, files in os.walk(PATH)
                 for file in glob(os.path.join(path, EXT))]
# The list of csv file directories is read into a DataFrame
# Dataframe is then split into columns based on the \\ found in the path

df_csv_path = pd.DataFrame(all_csv_files, columns =['Path'])
df_split_path = df_csv_path['Path'].str.split('\\', n = -1, expand = True)
df_split_path = df_split_path.rename(columns = {0:'Drive',1:'Main',2:'Project',3:'Imaging Folder', 4:'Experimental Group',5:'Experimental Rep',6:'File Name'})
df_csv_info = df_split_path.join(df_csv_path['Path'])

# Generates a Dataframe for each of the csv files found in directory
# Dataframe has a name based on the csv filename
for index in df_csv_info.index:
    filepath = ""
    filename = df_csv_info['File Name'].values[index]
    filepath = str(df_csv_info['Path'].values[index])
    filename = pd.read_csv(filepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a dictionary whose keys are the filenames and the values are the corresponding DataFrame. Instead of using `os.path` and `glob`, the modern approach is to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) from the standard library.

Assuming that you don't actually need the DataFrame containing the filenames and just want the DataFrames for each csv file, you can simply do

```
from pathlib import Path

PATH = Path("Z:\Adam")
EXT = "*.csv"

# dictionary holding all the files DataFrames with the format {"filename": file_DataFrame}
files_dfs = {}

# recursive search for csv files in PATH folder and subfolders 
for csv_file in PATH.rglob(EXT):
    filename = csv_file.name     # get the filename 
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)   # read the csv file as a DataFrame
    files_dfs[filename] = df     # add the DataFrame to the dictionary
```

Then, to access the DataFrame of a specific file you can do

```
filename_df = files_dfs["<filename>"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It did work very well. I will have to pay more attention to the modern way of doing these things as that was a very simple solution. Thank you again!

Comment: @Adam you're welcome! I'm glad I could teach you something new ;) Don't worry, it took me a long time to get to know `pathlib`.  The simplicity and effectiveness of the solutions is just a matter of practice! It takes time, but it comes naturally, you will see! Happy coding!